# InnerText of QuerySelector on custom tag comes with new line Charaters

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, selectors-api

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYS3u.png) -- Screen capture of chrome console

New Line charaters in innerText giving incomplete log.

```
const myString = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelectorAll('c-trailhead-rank')[0].innerText
});
console.log(myString);  // prints "Trailhead" instead of entire String as shown in image above
```

Comment: Could you try ```textContent``` instead of  ```innerText``` ??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I have tried, it is an empty string.

Comment: is this a tag `c-trailhead-rank` ?